# attic-shelve versus shelve. Are they complementary?

Tags: mercurial, shelving

I'm new to Mercurial and I'm a bit confused about how to stash changes like git. I dug into SO and found some use [attic extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AtticExtension) while others use [shelve extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShelveExtension). Are there any reason I should use one instead of the other?. Are they complementary?.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

Attic has not been updated since 2011, whereas Shelve is built-in. I was looking at the same thing myself, and decided to avoid Attic due to lack of maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

From Attic wiki:

> Shelve ... is almost entirely a subset of attic. In fact attic's hg shelve --interactive is calling 3 methods directly pulled from the hgshelve extension source code

Attic or Shelve is mostly question of habits and personal tastes

You *have* to explore [MQ Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) also: "Git's stash on steriods"

Answer (score 0):

I've been fine in using attic and am happy with it.  (We just upgraded from hg version 2.2.2 to 3.7.3 I do not know how well attic works on the later version.  Have to report back.)

In a search now I see there is a slightly newer forked version at https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/hgattic